# Captify + ScrollTo making page work sloow

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am making a single page website and I use **jquery ScrollTo** and **jquery Captify** on the page, but since I added Captify the page works really slow, scroll is slow and framed and even manual page scroll works kinda slow and messy ... anybody had this problem and can help ?

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you added Captify AND a lot of large images that may be your problem.

Comment: no, i just have 4 rows, 16 images of 230 x 120 .. and as soon as I take Captify out stuff works great ..

Comment: maybe someone knows something better then Captify ? I need a good caption over the images script . thanks a lot !